# Artifacts when css scaled in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, transform

Check this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XXrSD/1/

Code also produced below:

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="head">head</div>
<div>
    test
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    border: 10px solid brown;
    margin: 10px;
    transform: scale(0.6);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
    -o-transform: scale(0.6);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.6);
}

.head {
    height: 25px;
    background-color: brown;
}
```

You can see that Chrome leaves artifacts (gap between outer border and #head div) when scaled to 0.6 (and 0.3). But it looks good in Firefox. I guess its because of Chrome not being able to handle non-integer pixels. Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I need a block with border and a head at the top. And this block needs to be resized by the user and the inner content should scale.

Comment: If you actually scale your demo in Chrome, it doesn't seem to have issues. Only with the CSS3 transforms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is happening because of the antialiasing being applied to the object edges when scaled.
The browser incorrectly calculates the area that needs to be redrawn. The parts left behind are ghosts of the sections of the object that wasn't included in the area to be redrawn.

Adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` when scaling/transforming objects will resolve these odd looking artifacts in Chrome.

Updated example:
http://jsfiddle.net/robaldred/XXrSD/2/

Comment: It's a rendering issue, the browser incorrectly calculates the area that needs to be redrawn, so it doesn't redraw the complete object, leaving behind artifacts. The other answer from ivan is over kill, he's forcing the browser to redraw the entire page, a performance fail. If you don't need the backface of an object `webkit-backface-visibility` is the key.